# Word usage: difference between "bailar" and "danzar"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, diferencias-entre-palabras

Is there any difference between "bailar" and "danzar"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The meaning is the same but probably what changes is how it is applied. for example:

> —Vamos a ir a bailar.

> —Ella va a a clase
>   —¿De qué?
>   —De danza

We (Spanish speakers) usually use "danza" as the art, something with more structure and even more formal.

While "baile" is way more informal and it is the one we use as a verb. We usually don't say "Estoy danzando", we say "Estoy bailando".

At least here in Mexico.

Comment: It's the same in Spain, **danzar** is almost never used, we only use the noun **danza** as *"the artistic dance"*. And never ever ask someone: "*¿Quieres danzar conmigo?*" ;)

Comment: That's my experience in Mexico, as well. *danzar* is artistic or religious dancing. *bailar* is social dancing.

Answer (score 2):

At least in most parts of Latinoamerica, **danzar** is only for artistics purposes, for instance, people practicing **classic dance**.

Meanwhile the verb **bailar** is used for **casual dance**, I mean whatever rhythm people are dancing (salsa, merengue, tango, etc).

This is perhaps a little different than English where you mostly use **to dance** for everything related with this.

If you are inviting a woman to dance in a party you better say: *¿quieres bailar?*

Answer (score 2):

In Mexican Folkloric dance, a baile is a social dance. A danza is a ceremonial dance.

Answer (score 0):

In Chile, I've heard: "baile folclórico" as well as "danza folclórica", like in this YT video title: "4 Danzas Tradicionales Mapuches", referring to artistic dance.
However, as other answers have mentioned, any dance that involves the modern soul socially is almost always called: "baile". For examples, even the people who dance the artistic *cueca* usually say: "Vamos a bailar Cueca mañana."

I learned to say "bailar" when the chiquillos taught me to spin the trompo: "¿Sabes hacer bailar el trompo? -"¡Sí, lo sé hacer bailar hasta en el aire!"

And the ever-present fundraiser bingo is usually a "bingo bailable".

Answer (score 0):

**Danzar** in Spain could mean different things colloquially:

- Irse **danzando** (Marcharse / marcharse rápido) ~ Get out of here quickly.
- **Danzando** por ahí (Ir de un lado a otro sin hacer nada de provecho) ~ Going from side to side doing nothing beneficial.

Comment: Note though that the question asks about the difference between 'danzar' and 'bailar', not about what 'danzar' can mean depending on the context